# Use Vault to store clients PEM and KEY for later use with fetch

Tags: node.js, fetch, client-certificates, hashicorp-vault

I want to store clients PEM / KEY (PFX) for later use.
I want that the user who uploading his certificates to my server is the only one that can access it when login.

The certificates are then used to make a call to a payment provider.
The servier can only upload a new certificate and add a "role" that the login user is the only one that can access it. The server can also delete the certificates.

Tried Azure Key Vault and Hashicorp Vault but with no luck, probably because I have not yet found the information I need to make this work

This is my current working code but needs to add support for the login user certs and key.

```
const payment = bodyData => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch("https://mss.cpc.getswish.net/swish-cpcapi/api/v1/paymentrequests", {
      agent: new https.Agent({
        ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "cert/Swish_TLS_RootCA.pem")),
        // pfx: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "cert/no.pfx")),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(
          path.join(
            __dirname,
            "cert/Swish_Merchant_TestCertificate_1231181189.pem"
          )
        ),
        key: fs.readFileSync(
          path.join(
            __dirname,
            "cert/Swish_Merchant_TestCertificate_1231181189.key"
          )
        ),
        passphrase: "swish"
      }),
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(bodyData),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 201) {
          const location = res.headers.get("location");
          if (location !== null) {
            resolve(location.split("/").slice(-1)[0]);
          } else {
            reject(new Error("Unable to find 'location' parmas in header!"));
          }
        } else {
          return res.json()
        }
      }).then(reject)
      .catch(reject);
  });
};
```

Comment: did you try https://discuss.hashicorp.com/c/vault/30